# Issue to use JQuery GAE Dropload - Blobstore upload from drag and drop

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I would like to implement drag and drop file on my web page to upload file to Google Blobstore. Resources are sparse on the topic. One of the easiest way to achieve this seems to use [Jude Osborn jquery.gaedropload](https://github.com/JudeOsborn/jquery.gaedropload)

The description of the plugin is not very detailed for a poor skilled developer like me. But I finally get it working (as often starting writing my questions on Stackoverflow made me understood what is wrong in my code)

I will answer my own question, hopping that this could help others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe that's all obvious for experienced developers, but I spent hours (not counting days on this). I started from a working page with a classic HTML form to upload an image to the Blobstore before starting to use the jquery.gaedropload.

- Need to use jQuery 2.x (with jQuery 1.x the plugin fails with some error). Maybe that's normal since the plugin use HTML5 new FormData()
- generate_url: The doc says:

> A GAE URL that returns a blobstore URL.

We need to return the URL that we specified in the form before (when using an `<input type="file" name="uploadedFile" />` to upload a file). In the JSP file we used: `<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/uploadimage") %>"`

Therefore the get function we need to write is something like this:

```
public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )   throws ServletException, IOException {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/uploadimage")); 
}
```

- We cannot specify anymore the name of the input (before we used:  `name="uploadedFile"`). Now the name will be set by the plugin to `file0`. Therefore we need to modify the post called after the Blobstore upload:

  ```
  BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
  Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(request);
  List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("file0"); //Before was: uploadedFile
  ```
- When posting the form to upload the picture we need additional parameters (to identify what image is uploaded). Before they were in the form:

  ```
  <input type="hidden" name="setName" value="${ setName }">
  <input type="hidden" name="imageId" value="3">
  ```

Now we need to specify them when calling the pluging in extraFormData:

```
    $('#image3').gaeDropload( {
        extraFormData: { setName: "${ setName }", imageId: 4 },
        dragover: function() { //Show we can drop here
            $('#image3').css('background', 'red');
        },
        dragleave: function() { //Show we cannot drop anymore
            $('#image3').css('background', '');
        },
        afterDrop: function() { //Show we cannot drop anymore
            $('#image3').css('background', '');
        }
    }); //gaeDropload
```

Also the drag and drop functions can be added to show the user where he can drop.

image3 is just div around the image:

```
    <div class="span1 thumbnail" id="image3" ><img src="<%=set.getImageUrl(3)%>" alt=""></div>
```

The last point is to get the image refreshed after the upload. We need another get to return the new image URL. When calling the plugin we add:

```
        dropSuccess: function() { //Async call to get the new uploaded image
            $.ajax({
                url: '/blobimage?setName=${ setName }&buttonId=4',
                async: true,  //useless to specify, this is default
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#image3 > img').attr('src', data); //get img inside div
                }
            });
```

and the get will call

```
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
imagesService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(images[index]));
```

to get the updated image.

A great plugin after I understand how easy it is to use.